# mathaccent skewchar with XeTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode, accents

How can I get the dots in the correct position:

```
\font\test="XITS Math:script=math;mapping=italic" \skewchar\test=127
\XeTeXmathchardef\beta="0"1`β
\def\ddot{\XeTeXmathaccent"7"1"0308}
\textfont1=\test
$\ddot\beta$
\bye
```

[image]
vs. default CMI: `$\ddot\beta$\bye`: [image]

Comment: That's the 'correct' position.

Comment: Just to let you know, I finally managed to get into the root of this, and it should be fixed in XeTeX version of TeX Live 2012.

Comment: @khaled Awesome! Thanks for letting me know! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a XeTeX bug, LuaTeX give correct result:

```
\input ifxetex.sty
\ifxetex
  \XeTeXmathchardef\beta="0"1"1D6FD
  \def\ddot{\XeTeXmathaccent"7"1"0308}
\else
  \input luaotfload.sty
  \Umathchardef\beta="0"1"1D6FD
  \def\ddot{\Umathaccent"7"1"0308}
\fi
\font\test="XITS Math:script=math"
\textfont1=\test
$\ddot\beta$
\bye
```

When run with luatex I get (the same with MS Office 2007):

[image: luatex output]

BTW, `\skewchar` has no use in OpenType math fonts, so setting it makes no difference. Also the `/I` in your definition makes no sense either sense XITS Math comes only in regular style and there is no separate italic font, {Xe,Lua}TeX will waste time searching for non-existent then fall back to the regular one.

***Update***: The XeTeX bug has been fixed in 0.9998 (TeX Live 2012) version.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the excess "/I" after posting, but was lazy updating the question. `:-)`

Comment: I get wrong results with `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.63.0-2010091123` (TeX Live 2010), correct with `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011062107 (rev 4277)` (TeX Live 2011 test).

Comment: @egreg, IIRC 0.63 have several math accent related bugs that got fixed in some later version.

Comment: I see; it's quite surprising that Asana Math doesn't give problems with XeTeX, while XITS Math does.

Comment: @egreg: not much of surprise to me, it is not the first time I hit some obscure bug only triggered by my fonts that does not show anywhere else, if anyone knows a version of XITS that does not show this, I may try to see what change I did that might have caused it.

Comment: Strange thing: when I try `\dot` in LuaLaTeX 0.70 (TeX Live 2011) I get an error that I don't get with 0.63 (TeX Live 2010) although `\listfiles` shows no difference: `\l_um_growing_accents_bool` undefined.

Comment: @egreg: looks like a `unicode-math` bug, AFAIK it was fixed while ago (you may not see it with 0.63 because that code path is not used there), try updating to latest version of `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in XITS Math, as with Asana Math or Latin Modern Math it comes out right (and with no setting of the `\skewchar`).

Here is with Asana Math, I've added char U+1D5A0 for comparison

[image]

Comment: Thanks; I could've sworn it was working correctly with an earlier version. I'll wait a while before accepting, if you don't mind.

Comment: I don't remember to have seen this before; however one should recall that "XITS Math" is just an interim release.

Comment: Oh, almost forgot: Is there something I can do to correct with with TeX (because I have another font with the same problem)?

Comment: `$\skew3\ddot\beta$` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should also try this one:

In the preamble put:

```
\newcommand{\std}[1]{\overset{\:\mbox{\huge .\!.}}{#1}}
```

in the text put

```
\std{\beta}
```

With this new command for second time derivative you may easily control the location of the double-dot. For example, you may replace \: by \; or \, etc.