# Internal error: bad native font flag (XeLaTeX, fontspec, newtxmath, libertine, \dot)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, libertine, newtx

I'm trying to use `\dot{P}` in a math environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \dot{P}(t) + 1234567890
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Without the command `\dot` everything works as aspected.
With it I get the error: `Internal error: bad native font flag` and no output is produced.

Without the option `no-math` or the entire `fontspec` package (whose functionality I don't even need at the moment) there is an output compiled that includes a correct "dotted" P.
But the paranthesis, the plus sign and the numbers are not set in the Libertine font but rather in CM.
Also the spacing information from the `newtxmath` package seems to get lost (could be related to CM).

I already tried to change the package order. That resulted in an option clash error for fontspec and the same output as without the fontspec package at all.

Any suggestions?
I tried using the `libertine` package for `pdflatex` (without fontspec of course) which produced the same output as XeLaTeX without the fontspec package.

Versions/File List:

```
MikTeX                2.9 64bit, Win7
libertineotf.sty      2012/04/07 5.13-8
fontspec.sty          2012/05/06 v2.2b
newtxmath.sty         2012/06/25 v0.99
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This a bug in XeTeX resulting from mixing the OpenType (AKA "native") font Libertine with accent from the TFM font `newtxmath`. It didn't show up in earlier versions because of a [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22165/729) that prevented the proper utilisation of OpenType math accent positioning that has been recently fixed.

I tried to fix the new bug, but it seems to be a bit tricky. Anyway, I hope it will be fixed by the time of the next release.

Comment: Two years later, is this bug going to be fixed?

Comment: Mixing OpenType and TFM math fonts is not something I personally support, so it is a low priority issue, but feel free to open an issue in XeTeX bug tracker so it does not get forgotten again.

Comment: I posted https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/89/. (This is my first ever bug report on SF, so I hope I didn't get something wrong.)

Answer (score 4):

I (finally) found a solution with the help of [Hendrik's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60890/16595) to [Dot Derivative Discrepancy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42443/dot-derivative-discrepancy).

By simply adding

```
\renewcommand*\dot[1]{%
  \placeaccent{\acc@dot}{#1}%
  }
\renewcommand*\ddot[1]{%
  \placeaccent{\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot}{#1}%
  }
```

to his code snippet.

This does not help for other accents, of course.
For the `\hat{}` command I found the following solution:

```
\renewcommand*\hat[1]{%
  \placeaccent{\acc@hat}{#1}%
 }
```

where `\acc@hat` is defined as:

```
\def\acc@hat{\mbox{\raisebox{-1.27ex}[0ex][0ex]{\^{}}}}
```

Comment: Miktex 2.9 does not know `\placeaccent`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
  \def\conduce{⇝}
  \usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}
   \[ \dot{P}(t) + 1234567890 \]
   \[\not\conduce\]
   \[\not\leadsto\]
\end{document}
```

Here the line `\[ \dot{P}(t) + 1234567890 \]` is rendered fine

Instead in this example the command `\not\leadsto` will crash; it does not crash if `unicode-math` is not used, but no symbol appears; the command `\not\conduce` does work (but it looks bit ugly).

Note that here Libertine font is used, but this is not relevant; I tried adding `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}` and/or `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` and it behaves the same.

So, to answer the OP: use `setmainfont`