# fontspec/mathspec ruins my parentheses with beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, fontspec, mathspec

My problem appears to be related to this earlier post:

[Parentheses differ (XeLaTeX, fontspec, newtxmath, libertine)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63410/parentheses-differ-xelatex-fontspec-newtxmath-libertine)

but mine seems even simpler.  My problem is that when I compile a simple beamer presentation and use the fontspec or mathspec packages, the parentheses are spaced poorly.  As an MWE, when I compile the following with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}  
\frame{
Hello!  $f(x)=x^2$
}
\end{document}
```

I get just what I would want:

[image: a good picture with properly spaced parentheses]

However, when I uncomment the fontspec bit,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}  
\frame{
Hello!  $f(x)=x^2$
}
\end{document}
```

I see the following:

[image: a bad picture with ugly parentheses]

Does anyone know what can be causing this?  I don't see mention of parentheses  in the documentation.

Comment: I think the problem is `beamer`+`fontspec`, not with `fontspec`. In fact `beamer` sets all the text (including math) in sans serif and this causes the problem. I guess I've seen similar threads in this site, but at the moment I can't find one...

Comment: BTW: It's not a good practice to load `fontenc` when compiling with xetex, but adding the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` seems to solve the problem, until you get a better answer...

Answer (score 7):

XeTeX fails to set the correct italic correction in math (http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2011-March/020318.html) when open type fonts are used. I would suggest to use the normal T1-encoded font for the letters_

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{T1}{lmss}{\mddefault}{it}%
  }


\begin{document}

$f(x)$

\end{document}
```

### Edit 2017

With the new latex format which uses opentype fonts by default with xelatex you will get the wrong spacing without any external packages like `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\AtBeginDocument{%
%      \DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{T1}{lmss}{\mddefault}{it}%
%      }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[f(x)\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use the `mathserif` option and want to stay with classical Computer Modern, do `\DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{OT1}{cmr}{\mddefault}{it}`.