# Math kerning in Beamer with XeLaTeX vs. PDFLaTeX

Tags: beamer, math-mode, xetex, pdftex, lmodern

Consider this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
  $fft$
\end{document}
```

With PDFLaTeX, it turns out as expected:

[image: large spacing]

If I compile with XeLaTeX, however, the kerning is very different:

[image: small spacing]

If I use the *article* class, it is always the first variant.  If I use *beamer* with the *lmodern* package in XeLaTeX (which I am not supposed to do, as I understand), it also turns out right again.

How can this different behavior be explained, and what is the correct way to make sure that I always get the first variant?  I am using Debian stretch with TeX Live package version 2016.20170123-5.

(Note: I know that I should use `\mathit` to name multi-letter variables.)

Weirdly, on an older installation with Debian jessie and TeX Live 2014.20141024-2+deb8u1, also get the second variant with PDFLaTeX and *lmodern*, but I do not get the first variant with XeLaTeX and *lmodern*.

Comment: See https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/375#issuecomment-285613180

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132835/fontspec-mathspec-ruins-my-parentheses-with-beamer ???

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a duplicate, as I cannot reproduce the other thread.  For me, it produces the bad result with and without fontspec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
  $fft$
\end{document}
```