# XeTeX and polyglossia: \normalfont problem solving leads to errors: Undefined control sequence. \selectlanguage *{latex}

Tags: fonts, xetex, errors, languages, polyglossia

I have to use XeTeX, because it helps to set an arbitary font both in a text and math mode (or [newtxmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210261/newtxmath-and-polyglossia-problem) in a math mode).

I've noticed that the `polyglossia` package has a bug with the `\normalfont` command. [Here](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/203) is a detailed description of this bug by @egreg.

After the `polyglossia` package updating (to a recent version) in MikTeX the problem is fixed, however the following errors have been appeared:

```
    Undefined control sequence. ...ctlanguage *[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
Undefined control sequence. ...ctlanguage *[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
Encoding scheme `' unknown. ...ctlanguage *[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
Undefined control sequence. ^^I\begin{document}
    Undefined control sequence. ^^I\begin{document}
        Encoding scheme `' unknown. ^^I\begin{document}
            Undefined control sequence. ^^I\begin{abstr}
                Undefined control sequence. ^^I^^I\par{\normalfont
                    Undefined control sequence. ^^I^^I\par{\normalfont
                        Encoding scheme `' unknown. ^^I^^I\par{\normalfont
                            Undefined control sequence. ^^I\end{abstr}
                        Undefined control sequence. ^^I\end{abstr}
                    Encoding scheme `' unknown. ^^I\end{abstr}
                Undefined control sequence. ^^I\end{document}
            Undefined control sequence. ^^I\end{document}
        Encoding scheme `' unknown. ^^I\end{document}
    Undefined control sequence. ...ctlanguage *[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
    Undefined control sequence. ...ctlanguage *[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
    Encoding scheme `' unknown. ...ctlanguage *[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
    Overfull \hbox (29.36624pt too wide) in paragraph
```

in MWE:

```
        \documentclass[extrafontsizes,a4paper,*pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}   %[no-math] How can I use the Newton instead of newtxmath?
    %\usepackage{newtxmath} %math font of TNR type
    \usepackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21]   
    \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}  %
    \setotherlanguage{english}       
    \setmainfont{Arial} %% 
%   \setsansfont{Newton}                  
%   \setmonofont{Newton}
\newenvironment{abstr}{\small\itshape}{\normalfont\normalsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstr}
    \par{\normalfont Key \textbf{words}.} Hey!
\end{abstr}
\newcommand{\fn}{\expandafter\string\the\font}
{\normalsize\selectfont ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames\fn}
\fontname\font\\
$ a+b$
\end{document}
```

Here is a good output:[image]

How to escape these errors? Please, I need your help!

Best regards,
Vladimir

**UPD1** MWE is updated.

**UPD2** the screenshot of the TexStudio

[image]

**UPD3:** I've followed the recommendations of @DavidCarlisle and @UlrikeFischer to go through the full log file. After that I've found the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413775/error-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-cyrillic-script).

Comment: Start by making an mwe that actually can be tested on other pc. I don't have the newton font and `abstr` in not a defined environment.

Comment: note that the errors that you show are not the format of a tex error message, which would show _which_ command is undefined.  If that is a "summary" of the errors from your editor, ignore that and show the errors from the log file, in a code block so line endings are preserved.

Comment: If I comment out the newton font loading I just get a single error from your example that `! LaTeX Error: Environment abstr undefined.` which is not surprising as it is not defined anywhere in this code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you the MWE is updated!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, what font is better to use?

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko do you need to specify _any_ font to show your error? The idea is to use the minimum amount of code that shows the problem.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko you have added a code block, but as I say they are not tex error messages and they do not show which command is undefined. The tex error messages from the log file will not be of that form.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the problem on my PC is with any language, I've just reduced `\setmainfont`. I need to use `Newton`, but now the problem is not associated with this font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'll update the topic with a screenshot in few seconds...

Comment: you have now used Arial (which I have actually) but many users will not, you could have left this out  altogether. I would guess that you don't have russian language support installed in texlive or miktex (you haven't said which you are using)

Comment: Show the complete log-file. And delete first the aux-file and recompile then at least twice.

Comment: note the fact that texstudio scrambles the undefined command error messages  is a reported bug you could comment there and see if it could be fixed https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I've found the full log file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I've submitted the full log file in the 3rd UPD.

Comment: You seem to have made updates only as user, all files in the main tree are quite outdated and now you have clashes. Always do updates in both modes: as user and as admin.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for your time. The problem seems to be solved now. I've followed your and DavidCarlise's recommendations and fixed the bug.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413775/error-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-cyrillic-script

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for your time. The problem seems to be solved now. I've followed your and UlrikeFischer's recommendations and fixed the bug. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413775/error-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-cyrillic-script