# Math digits are in CM with newtxmath and fontspec (LuaLaTeX, TeX Live 2017)

Tags: math-mode, luatex, fontspec, times, newtxmath

This issue is not new on this site, but I’ve tried earlier solutions and neither works for me. Related questions:

- [Math digits are rendered in CM when using libertine and newtxmath with XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2016](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347566/math-digits-are-rendered-in-cm-when-using-libertine-and-newtxmath-with-xelatex-i)
- [Caveats of newtxmath and fontspec together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159785/caveats-of-newtxmath-and-fontspec-together)

My goal is to use `newtxmath` together with setting system OpenType fonts through `fontspec`. No matter in which order I load the package, the digits in math mode are rendered in Computer Modern, not Times.

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Text: 2, Math: \(x=\sqrt{2}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Per the `newtxmath` documentation:

> As far as I can tell, newtxmath works with both [XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX], but requires a very specific loading order and choice of
>   options. [...] the math options must all be loaded prior to loading and using
>   fontspec.

Which I’ve done right in my opinion. My packages are all up-to-date as well.

I’ve tried to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390196/75284) for the Times font, but couldn’t make it work.

Comment: Not sure the quoted passage from the user guide of the `nextx` package is (still) correct. For sure, `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` followed by `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` works fine.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, your proposal does work, but I still want to set my main font via fontspec so I can use the Times OTF files I want (using Semibold in my case) instead of the `newtxtext` fonts.

Comment: Since `newtx` is based on TeX Gyre Termes, why not just use `unicode-math` and `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke: This is a good alternative, but I'm still curious about what is happening in my MWE and how to fix it ... and the `\pi` is disturbingly mirrored with the `TeX Gyre Termes Math` font.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`newtxmath` more or less assumes that the default encoding is T1 or OT1. But you can reset the operator font:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{ntxtlf}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{ntxtlf}{b}{n}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%
\begin{document}
Text: 2, Math: \(x=\sqrt{2}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is to give times the newtx-family name, so that newtxmath can use it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]

\usepackage{newtxmath}

%
\begin{document}
Text: 2, Math: \(x=\sqrt{2}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've found that your second solution with `[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]` disables OpenType superior figures (`VerticalPosition=Superior` in `fontspec`), so I'm using the first solution now.

Comment: I am trying this solution with Linux Libertine instead of Times New Roman, but the numbers are still coming differently.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `no-math` option and use the trick in my answer to [Math digits are rendered in CM when using libertine and newtxmath with XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2016](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347566/), but augmented for taking care also of other glyphs.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\DeclareSymbolFont{oldoperators}{OT1}{ntxtlf}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{oldoperators}{bold}{OT1}{ntxtlf}{b}{n}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`0}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`1}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`2}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`3}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`4}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`5}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`6}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`7}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`8}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`9}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"00}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"01}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"02}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"03}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"04}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"05}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"06}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"07}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"08}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"09}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"0A}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{!}{\mathclose}{operators}{"21}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{operators}{"2B}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3A}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{;}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3B}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3D}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{?}{\mathclose}{operators}{"3F}%
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"28}{largesymbols}{"00}%
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{largesymbols}{"01}%
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {operators}{"5B}{largesymbols}{"02}%
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{operators}{"5D}{largesymbols}{"03}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\acute}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"B4}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\grave}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"60}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\ddot}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"A8}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\tilde}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"7E}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"16}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\breve}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"15}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\check}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"14}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"5E}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"5F}%
  \DeclareMathAccent{\mathring}{\mathalpha}{oldoperators}{"17}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathdollar}{\mathord}{operators}{"24}%
}

\begin{document}

Text: 2, Math: \(x=\sqrt{2}+1234567890\)

!+:;=?()[]

${!}{+}{:}{;}{=}{?}{(}{)}{[}{]}$

\'a\`a\"a\~a\=a\u{a}\v{a}\^a\.a\r{a}

$
\acute{\mathrm{a}}
\grave{\mathrm{a}}
\ddot{\mathrm{a}}
\tilde{\mathrm{a}}
\bar{\mathrm{a}}
\breve{\mathrm{a}}
\check{\mathrm{a}}
\hat{\mathrm{a}}
\dot{\mathrm{a}}
\mathring{\mathrm{a}}
$

$\Gamma\Delta\Theta$

\end{document}
```

Some accents must be taken from `newtx` instead of Times New Roman, for technical limitations.

[image]

Comment: This solution now has the equal sign `=` (and possibly others) in CM, though.

Comment: @lblb I used the equals and plus sign from Times New Roman, because they are quite different in NewTX. There are small differences in tilde, bar, breve, hat, check and dot, for technical limitations in the font.

Comment: Please add the missing `\makeatother`. Is it even necessary there? I see no `@` signs.

Comment: @lblb Thanks, probably `\makeatletter` was a remain from earlier code.