Drawing table in LaTeX
This is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{asdagd}
\author{Finn Krammer}
\date{June 2024}
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  % source: Second proposed fix from the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394137
  \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeXGyreTermes-Regular}[
       BoldFont       = TeXGyreTermes-Bold ,
       ItalicFont     = TeXGyreTermes-Italic ,
       BoldItalicFont = TeXGyreTermes-BoldItalic,
       NFSSFamily     = ntxtlf]
  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros Regular}[
       Scale=.9,
       BoldFont       = TeX Gyre Heros Bold,
       ItalicFont     = TeX Gyre Heros Italic,
       BoldItalicFont = TeX Gyre Heros BoldItalic]
  \setmonofont[StylisticSet={1,3},Scale=.9]{inconsolata}
  \RequirePackage{newtxmath}
\else
  \RequirePackage{newtxtext}
  \RequirePackage{newtxmath}
  % EN: looks good with times, but no equivalent for lualatex found,
  %     therefore replaced with inconsolata
  %\RequirePackage[zerostyle=b,scaled=.9]{newtxtt}
  \RequirePackage[varl,scaled=.9]{inconsolata}
\fi
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\usepackage{array} %increases tex's buffer size and enables ``>'' in tablespecs
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
% DE: Eine Zelle, die sich über mehrere Zeilen erstreckt.
%     Siehe Beispieltabelle in Kapitel 2
\usepackage{multirow}
\documentclass[a4paper,
twoside,
bibliography=totoc,
headsepline,
cleardoublepage=empty,
parskip=half,
draft=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{multicol, multirow}

\pagestyle{preamble}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{preamble}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\tiny

\centering

\caption{Magill's Adaptation of Gentile's Taxonomy of Motor Skills \cite{Magill2014, JanetCarr2000}}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|}

\hline

 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Body Stability}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Body Transport}} \\

 \hline

 & \textbf{No Object Manipulation} & \textbf{Object Manipulation} & \textbf{No Object Manipulation} & \textbf{Object Manipulation} \\

\hline

\multirow{5}{2cm}{{}&\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and No Intertrial Variability}} & \textbf{1A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{1B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{1C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{1D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability  \\

\hline


\multirow{5}{2cm}{{}&\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}} & \textbf{2A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{2B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{2C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{1D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability  \\

\hline


\multirow{5}{2cm}{{}&\textbf{In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and No intertrial Variability}} & \textbf{3A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{3B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{3C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{3D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability  \\

\hline


\multirow{5}{2cm}{{}&\textbf{In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}} & \textbf{4A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{4B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{4C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability \\

& \textbf{4D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability  \\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}

\end{document}


And it works just fine, except for the \hline statements.
The separating lines are not drawn across the whole table. Instead, it looks like this:
[]
How do I fix the separating lines which should be between the rows? The very last line does not also complete the table but is in the bottom right field.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

The code does not compile for me.

I added a bunch of the used packages, it should work now

error: 52: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands. draft=false]{

huh, weird, it generates a pdf for me in a brand new project...

@Q170 do remember that generate a PDF and compile without errors are not the same thing. Don't ignore compilation errors. And your example does have two \documentclass's and only one is allowed, so please fix your code.

First, add \arraybackslash after all your \raggedrights in the table preamble. \raggedright redefines \\ in such a way that it doesn't end table rows anymore.

You also have two \end{document}. This won't cause any errors or problems, but is not necessary. You are loading packages twice and you've included preamble which can't possibly be needed to reproduce the issue. This should be a minimal example. Unless the issue specifically involves the results of compiling with different engines, we don't need the font setup for both. And very likely we don't need the font setup for either.

A solution with tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Magill's Adaptation of Gentile's Taxonomy of Motor Skills \cite{Magill2014, JanetCarr2000}}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={*5{X[l]}},
  columns={font=\scriptsize},
  row{1,2}={font=\scriptsize\bfseries},
  column{1}={font=\scriptsize\bfseries},
  hline{1,2}={2-Z}{solid},
  hline{3-Z}={solid},  
  vline{1}={3-Z}{solid},
  vline{2-Z}={solid},  
  }
  & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Body Stability & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Body Transport& \\
  & No Object Manipulation & Object Manipulation & No Object Manipulation & Object Manipulation\\
  Stationary Regulatory Conditions and No Intertrial Variability 
    & {\textbf{1A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & {\textbf{1B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & {\textbf{1C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & {\textbf{1D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} \\
  Stationary Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability 
    & {\textbf{2A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability} 
    & {\textbf{2B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & {\textbf{2C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability} 
    & {\textbf{1D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability} \\  
  In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and No intertrial Variability 
    & {\textbf{3A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & {\textbf{3B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & {\textbf{3C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability}
    & {\textbf{3D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability} \\  
  In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability 
    & {\textbf{4A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & {\textbf{4B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & {\textbf{4C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & {\textbf{4D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



I suspect that you looking for something like this:


Above result I got after removing all errors from your code:
wrong specification for multirow cells. Instead of

\multirow{5}{2cm}{{}&\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and No Intertrial Variability}} 

should be
\multirow{5}{2cm}{\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}} 

or even better
\multirow{5}{=}{\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}} 


remove all not needed \\ 
to last column specification add \arraybackslash (see MWE below)
it is not clvear why you use \multirow cell. It actualy spanned just one row

_ two solutions:

first considering your multirow cells,

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \tiny

    \centering
\caption{Magill's Adaptation of Gentile's Taxonomy of Motor Skills \cite{Magill2014, JanetCarr2000}}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Body Stability}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Body Transport}} \\
\hline

    & \textbf{No Object Manipulation} & \textbf{Object Manipulation} & \textbf{No Object Manipulation} & \textbf{Object Manipulation} \\

    \hline
\multirow{5}{2cm}{\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and No Intertrial Variability}} 
    & \textbf{1A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability 
    & \textbf{1B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability 
    & \textbf{1C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability 
    & \textbf{1D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability  \\

\hline


\multirow{5}{2cm}{\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}} 
    & \textbf{2A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{2B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{2C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{1D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability  \\  

\hline


\multirow{5}{2cm}{\textbf{In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and No intertrial Variability}} 
    & \textbf{3A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{3B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{3C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{3D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability  \\  

\hline

\multirow{5}{2cm}{\textbf{In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}} 
    & \textbf{4A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{4B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{4C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{4D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


second without multirow cells:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \tiny

    \centering
\caption{Magill's Adaptation of Gentile's Taxonomy of Motor Skills \cite{Magill2014, JanetCarr2000}}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
                |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Body Stability}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Body Transport}} \\
\hline

    & \textbf{No Object Manipulation} & \textbf{Object Manipulation} & \textbf{No Object Manipulation} & \textbf{Object Manipulation} \\

    \hline
\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and No Intertrial Variability} 
    & \textbf{1A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability 
    & \textbf{1B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability 
    & \textbf{1C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability 
    & \textbf{1D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline No intertrial variability  \\

\hline
\textbf{Stationary Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}
    & \textbf{2A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{2B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{2C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{1D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Stationary regulatory conditions, \newline Intertrial variability  \\  

\hline
\textbf{In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and No intertrial Variability}
    & \textbf{3A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{3B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{3C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{3D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline No intertrial variability  \\  

\hline
\textbf{In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability}
    & \textbf{4A} \newline Body stability, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{4B} \newline Body stability, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{4C} \newline Body transport, \newline No object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability 

    & \textbf{4D} \newline Body transport, \newline Object, \newline Regulatory conditions in motion, \newline Intertrial variability  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

Both ab8ove examples gives the same result.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Magill's Adaptation of Gentile's Taxonomy of Motor Skills \cite{Magill2014, JanetCarr2000}}
\scriptsize
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}*5{X[l]}}[hvlines,corners,cell-space-limits=2pt]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
  & \Block{1-2}{Body Stability} & & \Block{1-2}{Body Transport}  \\
  & No Object Manipulation & Object Manipulation & No Object Manipulation & Object Manipulation\\
  Stationary Regulatory Conditions and No Intertrial Variability 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{1A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{1B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{1C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{1D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ No intertrial variability} \\
  Stationary Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{2A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability} 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{2B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{2C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability} 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{1D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Stationary regulatory conditions, \\ Intertrial variability} \\  
  In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and No intertrial Variability 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{3A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{3B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability} 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{3C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability}
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{3D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ No intertrial variability} \\  
  In-Motion Regulatory Conditions and Intertrial Variability 
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{4A} \\ Body stability, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{4B} \\ Body stability, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{4C} \\ Body transport, \\ No object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability}
    & \Block[t]{}{\textbf{4D} \\ Body transport, \\ Object, \\ Regulatory conditions in motion, \\ Intertrial variability} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


