# Neo Euler Math Font with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm trying to use the following code to generate my xelatex PDF document. The main problem is that I get the error

```
! Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'
```

when I compile my document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
% XeLaTeX
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\blindmathtrue
\begin{document}
    \blindmathpaper
    \blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

The problem goes away if I remove the line

```
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
```

but then I get Latin Modern Math fonts, which is not ideal. So, my question is, how to properly use Neo Euler Math fonts with XeLaTeX. I'm using TexLive 2015.

Comment: There is something in `\blindmathpaper` that triggers the error.

Comment: After searching for more than hours, I just found out the right answer. And that is to use unicode-math as `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}` which fixes most of the things, except the facts that the double quotes are now replaced by square boxes. This happens even when there is no blindtext package used.

Comment: The problem are the math accents (\bar, \dot etc), (a similar error but with legacy fonts is described here:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63244/internal-error-bad-native-font-flag-xelatex-fontspec-newtxmath-libertine). But as only Neo Euler triggers the error you should imho make a bug report here https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf/issues.

Comment: AMS Euler (and therefore Neo Euler) isn’t intended as a text font for the body of your document.  A text font that matches it well is Palatino (and its clones, such as TeX Gyre Pagella), also created by Hermann Zapf.