# Incompatibility between `MnSymbol` and `unicode-math`?

Tags: packages, unicode-math, option-clash, mnsymbol

The following code

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{MnSymbol,unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$A\bar\smalltriangleup B$

\end{document}
```

results in

```
!Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'
```

with no output at all.

I need both packages for various reasons, is there any way around this error?

Comment: Works ok with lualatex, regarding xelatex see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63244/internal-error-bad-native-font-flag-xelatex-fontspec-newtxmath-libertine

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for pointing this out! So the current status with `xelatex` is "still a bug"? It's been quite a while...