# \Umathaccent works with Type 1 fonts but not with OpenType

Tags: xetex, unicode, accents, opentype, type1

I am in the early stages of experimenting with accents in XeTeX/Unicode.  This began because I wanted to be able to use MathTime Pro 2's bold and heavy accents without necessarily making the symbol they accent bold or heavy.  As I have been trying to move as much as possible to OpenType fonts, I have been trying to use unicode commands wherever applicable.  I am not and do not plan to load `unicode-math`, even if that means I have to reinvent the wheel in places, because of its interference with `mtpro2`.  I solved the original problem using `\Umathaccent`, but in the process discovered a strange problem that I have not yet been able to solve.  If I use a standard Type 1 font (.pfb), the method works.  If I use an .otf font, it gives me a vague XeTeX error and refers me to log files, where I have yet to find anything helpful.  The following code...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\stixupper{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[NFSSFamily=stixupper,Script=Math,Scale=MatchUppercase]
\DeclareSymbolFont{sxup}{TU}{stixupper}{m}{n}

\def\nuhat{\Umathaccent 7 \symsxup "002C6}

\begin{document}
    
    \[
    \nuhat{H}
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

... gives the error

```
Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_BJdEUf".tex

! Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'
Process exited with error(s)
```

This answer is probably relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63249/224317

Comment: I get `! Internal error: bad native font flag in \`map_char_to_glyph`  from xetex texlive 2023

Comment: it works in lualatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found this based on your error: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63244/internal-error-bad-native-font-flag-xelatex-fontspec-newtxmath-libertine.  I changed the command to `\nuhat{\symsxup H}` and it worked, albeit horribly aligned. Is it possible that there is still a bug that crops up when you mix OpenType and Type 1 fonts in a symbol/accent pair?

Comment: You presumably got the same error? yes (xetex is only partially supported so it's quite like likely bugs reported are still not fixed)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, the same error.  Well, it's not a dealbreaker for me, but it is something to consider.  I wonder if I should also try to migrate to LuaLaTeX...

Comment: You could have put that error in the question (and removed all the txmath lines which obscured debugging for a while) but I guess this is a duplicate and we can close?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, I edited the question and included a link to the answer I mentioned.

Comment: @MikePugh If you do decide to migrate to LuaLaTeX, you might want to look at https://github.com/zauguin/mtpro2-lua/. There I made a proof of concept of using a Lua based font wrapper to allow MathTime Pro 2 Lite to be loaded with unicode-math as if it were an Opentype font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xetex doesn't support placing opentype accents on a classic tfm base. If you *really* need to, if you make the base not a single character, it uses its generic rules to stick the accent on a box, but you may need to fine tune the positioning as the font metrics can not help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\stixupper{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[NFSSFamily=stixupper,Script=Math,Scale=MatchUppercase]
\DeclareSymbolFont{sxup}{TU}{stixupper}{m}{n}


\def\nuhat{\Umathaccent 7 \symsxup "002C6}

\begin{document}

\[
\nuhat{H{}}
\]

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

in xelatex.

Without the `{}` you get this from lualatex

[image]